# How to tag a build with it's pull request on TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

In VSTFS I'm trying to create a build tag that gets the source (pull request) from a merge. I've been trying to do it using variables such as those described by Microsoft in this link: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer%2Cbatch

Just so you can get a little more vision on the issue:

- Someone creates a Pull Request (it has a hash of it's own);
- The Pull Request is approved and commited;
- There's a merge;
- A build is triggered;
- It's tagged.

Currently we're just using the BuildNumber variable on the tag, we want to add to it the source Pull Request ID.

Images:

[Variable Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrErQ.jpg)

[Resulting Build Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBNax.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tag the build you can use the variable `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId`, it returns the Pull Request Id.

Comment: I've tried like that, do you know something that would make system variables stop working, and how to work around it?

Comment: It just uses the "variable" as plain text instead of replacing it for it's actual value

Comment: Can you share screenshots of what you tried and what you got?

Comment: I just added two images, one of the input, the other of the result, as you might notice, I've tried a few paths, not only the system varible, but in most cases the result is just the variable as text, not the value of it.

Comment: Could it be the TFS version?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: Version 16.131.27701.1

Comment: It should work, you have TFS 2018 and I tested it now in TFS 2017 and it works. the builds in the image you added, all the builds are pull requests builds?

Comment: Yes, all of them are PR triggered.

Comment: Try to report a bug in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html

Comment: Let me try to explain it in more detail, a PR is created, a build is triggered, the PR is approved, a release is triggered, the tag should be there on the release.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you talking about the build. the variable not available to the release pipeline. you can in the build use the `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId`, and in the release use the `Build.BuildNumber`, it will take the PR id from the build number.

Comment: And I got this: 
Build 4175_$(Build.BuildNumber)_20190211_1

Comment: I think it's not gonna work, so thanks, I'll keep looking, if you know any other way let me know.

But, thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you entered in the Build pipeline options and in the Release pipeline options?

Comment: Build: $(date:yyyyMMdd)_$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)_$(rev:_r)

Release: $(BuildID)_$(Build.BuildNumber)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:_r)

Comment: In the build do you success to get PR id? in the release do you mean `Build.BuildNumber` and not `BuildNumber` ? (if no, change it to Build.BuildNumber)

Comment: Yes, I got the PR in the build.

Comment: It should work. Please share the build summary page and release summary page.